# Python: Deleting a list element based on elements from another list

Tags: python

I have two lists here. I am shuffling list `i`, checking it's first element and then deleting the corresponding element from list `j` e.g. if after a shuffle, `i[0] == 3`, then i want to delete element 3 from list '`j`'.

```
i = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
random.shuffle(i)

j = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

if i[0] == 'a':
    del j[0]
elif i[0] == 'b':
    del j[1]
elif i[0] == 'c':
    del j[2]
elif i[0] == 'd':
    del j[3]
elif i[0] == 'e':
    del j[4]
elif i[0] == 'f':
    del j[5]
elif i[0] == 'g':
    del j[6]
elif i[0] == 'h':
    del j[7]
```

Is there a way to do this task without listing out if statements like this? As it stands, if `i[0] == 6`, then several if statements need to be checked which is a waste of processing power, in principle.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: This isn't very clear. All your if/elif conditions are the same.

Comment: Is "a" a letter or a variable? For a letter you need to write 'a', for a variable you need to define it.

Comment: It's a variable, it is defined, that just isn't shown.

Comment: So what happens if more than one variable has the same value? if you say i[0]==a you are comparing values and not variable names.

Comment: This isn't my actual code, I just needed to know the underlying principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
base = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
random.shuffle(i)

j = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

del j[base.index(i[0])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
j.remove(i[0])
```

To remove element with value i[0] from list j.

[Edit] Updated:

```
import random

i = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
k=i[:]

random.shuffle(i)

print i
print k
print j

j = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print i[0]
print k.index(i[0])
del j[k.index(i[0])]
print j
```

Comment: This would have worked, but my original post was incorrect: I have now updated it. The elif statements are now different.

Comment: I am trying to use your method again, only with i = [(4.5,5.6],[4.3,5.3)] and j as [(3.2,1.5],[4.3,5.2])]. I don't want to delete any element, I want to return the corresponding j element based on i (after a shuffle). The k=i[:] does not work with these lists. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform removing of `j` item with [index method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
i = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
random.shuffle(i)

j = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
del j[j.index(i[0])]

random.shuffle(i)
del j[j.index(i[0])]
```

Comment: This would have worked, but my original post was incorrect. I have now updated it, the elif statement are now different. Apologies.

Comment: I am trying to use your method again, only with i = [(4.5,5.6],[4.3,5.3)] and j as [(3.2,1.5],[4.3,5.2])]. I don't want to delete any element, I want to return the corresponding j element based on i (after a shuffle). The k=i[:] does not work with these lists. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

> if after a shuffle, i[0] == 3, then i want to delete element 3 from list 'j'.

If that's all you're trying to accomplish, just go for something like `j.remove(i[0])`

Or, if you insist on using `del`, `del j[i[0]]`, which I wouldn't (only use del when you want to make clear to a reader of your code that this variable will no longer be used in your program further down in your code. Here, it works, but `list.remove` better expresses your intent to a reader.)

Read up about what else you can do with lists in the python documentation on lists, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).